# Unable to fill src value using JS in iframe

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body style="text-align:center;">
    <iframe id="gfgFrame" src=""
        style="height: 50vh; width: 600px;">
    </iframe>

    <input type="text" id = "xxx">
  <p id = "u"></p>
    <button onclick="navigate()">
        Click it
    </button>

    <script>
    var url = document.getElementById("xxx");
        function navigate() {
            document.getElementById("gfgFrame").setAttribute("src", url);
      document.getElementById("u").innerHTML = "Hello";
    }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

If I enter a URL, it's not working.
I have seen solutions on stackoverflow. I have also tried the other method, which is

```
    <script>
var url = document.getElementById("xxx");
       function navigate() {
            document.getElementById("gfgFrame").src
                = url;
        }
    </script>
```

Please forgive my intendation. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: `.setAttribute("src", url.value);` (url is the <input> element)

Comment: Your `var url = document.getElementById("xxx");` will run once on load, and never update if the input changes (And is also the input itself, not its value)

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Missed something so simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You requesting element itself, not the value of this field, see:

```js
const urlBlock = document.getElementById("xxx"); // get url text input

function navigate() {
  const iframe = document.getElementById("gfgFrame");
  const text = document.getElementById("u");
  
  // get url from input
  const url = urlBlock.value;
  
  iframe.setAttribute("src", url);
  text.innerHTML = "Hello";
}
```

```html
<iframe id="gfgFrame" src="https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page" style="height: 50vh; width: 600px;"></iframe>

<input type="text" id="xxx" value="https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page" />

<p id="u"></p>

<button onclick="navigate()">Click it</button>
```